# php unicode 16 bit

Tags: php, unicode, character-encoding

how can I append a 16 bit unicode character to a string in php

```
$test = "testing" . (U + 199F);
```

From what I see, \x only takes 8 bit characters aka ascii

Comment: By just passing the literal character? Works here.

Comment: Check out [mb_convert_encoding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) also

Comment: There is no such thing as a 16-bit Unicode character.  Unicode is 21 bits.

Comment: @tchrist 1 byte is 8 bits.
2 bytes is 16 bits.
Unicode is 2 bytes.

Comment: If you think Unicode is "2 bytes", then you have a great deal to learn. It isn’t.

Comment: @Drake - The unicode codepoints run from 0 to 1,114,111 (see the unicode FAQ at http://www.unicode.org/faq//utf_bom.html#utf16-1).  UTF-16 codes the most common 63k characters with a single 16-bit, and uses pairs of 16-bits (surrogates) for the other 1m codepoints.

Answer (score 0):

From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):

> PHP only supports a 256-character set, and hence does not offer native Unicode support.

You could enter a manually-encoded UTF-8 sequence, I suppose.

You can also type out UCS4 as byte sequence and use `iconv("UTF-32LE", "UTF-8", $str);` to convert it into UTF-8 for further processing. You just can't input the codepoint as a 32-bit code unit in one go.

Answer (score 0):

Unicode characters don't directly exist in PHP(*), but you can deal with strings containing bytes represent characters in UTF-8 encoding. Here's one way of converting a numeric character code point to UTF-8:

```
function unichr($i) {
    return iconv('UCS-4LE', 'UTF-8', pack('V', $i));
}

$test= 'testing'.unichr(0x199F);
```

(*: and ‘16-bit’ Unicode characters don't exist at all; Unicode has code points way beyond U+FFFF. There are 16-bit ‘code units’ in UTF-16, but that's an ugly encoding you're unlikely to meet in PHP.)

Answer (score 0):

Because unicode is just multibyte and PHP only supports single byte you can create multibyte characters with multiple single bytes :)

```
$test = "testing\x19\x9F";
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
$test = "testing" . "\u199F";
```

Comment: Already have, doesn't work at all and i believe php doesn't even support "\u".